# Number of entries are not divisible by x in the n th row of triangle

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, stirling-numbers

I recently read the method for finding the number of entries that are not divisible by **x**(is a prime) in the **n**th row of Pascal's triangle. Similarly how to find number of entries not divisible by **x**(is a prime) in the **n**th row of  triangle formed by the  Stirling numbers of the second kind?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What? What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Yeah . i tried to derive the formula . But no clue how to do it